# CI on GitHub -- Is the current version stable?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I was wondering if anyone is using the (official?) CI fork on GitHub https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter. I'd like to know if it's stable and safe to use CI, especially for small, no-frills, personal projects. Or it is like there is nothing but chaos in CI community and the framework is to be avoided at all costs? Please share your experience.

Comment: I've tried Yii, Laravel, and CakePHP. While CakePHP is simple to use, its conventions are driving me mad. Laravel and Yii are great, no doubt, but right now look like an overkill.

Comment: Primarily opinion based..

Comment: @icecub Really? All I'm asking is whether the specified fork can be used, from your experience. Of course for that you'd have to still be a CI developer.

Comment: Then you should refine your question so it can be answered with facts. Is it safe to use? Is it actively maintained? Asking if something is good or bad is asking for an opinion, which is against the rules. I'm not being mean or anything. I'm just pointing out your mistake so you can correct it. I'll remove the downvote inmediately when do so :)

Comment: @icecub I don't mind the downvote, really. But I thought my intent was obvious. Will rephrase the question. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's different versions on that page but you will probably be using either CI 2.2 (considered the stable release version) or CI Develop which is sometimes called CI 3.

Codeigniter framework has been acquired by British Columbia Institute of Technology - it was just announced a few days ago. 
https://ellislab.com/blog/entry/your-favorite-php-framework-codeigniter-has-a-new-home